# Is there any way to make a function permanent in math mode?

Tags: math-mode

I always have problems with the letter size of my document, but `\displaystyle` helps me to solve it, thus I always use it. Is there any way to make that a default setting, so that `$...$` would mean `$\displaystyle ...$`?
Any other solution which would solve this problem are welcome!

Comment: Use actual display-style math, i.e. `\[` and `\]` or one of amsmath’s environments.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel `\[ ... \]` creates a centered display. The OP wants `displaystyle` functionality for inline math.

Comment: @EthanBolker That’s what I’m getting at. Display-style math for inline math will create bad spacing between lines. Besides that, OP also welcomes “[a]ny other solution which would solve this problem”.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel I agree that `displaystyle` all the time is probably not wise. But it's what the OP seems to want. Some of the solutions here (but not the accepted one) at least allow for switching back and forth ...

Comment: `\displaystyle` does not alter the size of most letters just of operators such as `\sum` and the position of scripts. Using `\displaystyle` in inline math will almost always ruin the inter-line spacing in the paragraph, and is generally not recommended. What is the problem that you are trying to solve?

Comment: I agree with David: you *don't* want to do that.

Comment: I'm trying to solve that the numbers in my fractions are way too small for convenient reading. Considering I just started to learn TeX (like days ago), this was a good solution for me, and could solve this for just now. Maybe I'll regret that after I get to know the features of this language more deeply.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This [Wikibook tutorial on LaTeX](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Advanced_Mathematics#Forcing_.5Cdisplaystyle_for_all_math_in_a_document) has what you want:

> **Forcing \displaystyle for all math in a document**
>
> Put
>
> ```
> \everymath{\displaystyle}
> ```
>
> before `\begin{document}` to force all math to `\displaystyle`.

Comment: Better do `\everymath\expandafter{\the\everymath\displaystyle}` to avoid overwriting the contents of an earlier `\everymath`.

Comment: That was exactly what I was looking for! Thank you!

Comment: Also, if I want to make an exception, how do I do that? Or it cannot be done, after using this line?

Comment: @Sphery: just including a `\textstyle` (which is the opposite of `\displaystyle`) in your maths should do the trick.

Answer (score 6):

It is not clear that what you are asking is a good idea.  However, one option would be to start using `\(...\)` instead of `$...$` in your document, and redefine `\(` to add the code that you want.

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\g@addto@macro {\(} {\displaystyle}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
  You get $\frac{1}{2}$ with usual dollars,
  and \(\frac{1}{2}\) with the LaTeX syntax
  in which we hooked.
\end{document}
```

This redefinition of `\(` should be done after loading all packages, I think.  Another option, which is not as safe, is to use `\everymath\expandafter{\the\everymath\displaystyle}`.  The problem is that math mode is used internally a lot, and it may not be good to insert `\displaymath` in some constructions.

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\mymath}[1]{%
$\displaystyle #1 $}

\begin{document}

With \verb!$$! $\frac{1}{2}$, then with the new macro:
\mymath{\frac{1}{2}}.
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like this, as suggested by [LaTeX Wikibooks](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Advanced_Mathematics#Forcing_.5Cdisplaystyle_for_all_math_in_a_document):

```
\documentclass{article}

\everymath{\displaystyle}

\begin{document}

$\sum_{i=0}^{n}1+\frac{\pi_i}{1+\frac{\delta_i}{1+\ldots}}$ just for fun...

And just to compare: $$\sum_{i=0}^{n}1+\frac{\pi_i}{1+\frac{\delta_i}{1+\ldots}}$$

\end{document}
```

And this is the output:
[image]